# Is it possible to use Adobe Flash CS6 with a touchscreen laptop?

Tags: adobe-flash

I figured I didn't need a Wacom or anything due to my touchscreen laptop. Though, any time I try to use it, it simply scrolls around on the scene without actually drawing anything.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same problem and it prevents me from drawing in flash/photoshop because of the scrolling issue.

**For people reading this in 2016 onwards and asking the same question here is what worked for me:**

- Go to run and type "regedit" to edit the registry
- Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to get the find command and then type "panningdisabled"

It may take a while to search but it should hopefully find the registry value that deals with touchscrolling.

- The value should say 0 and you need to change this value to 1
- Reboot your computer

If you need to turn it back on then just repeat these same steps but change the value from 1 back to 0.

This might not work for everybody but I am using a Lenovo Flex, with Windows 8, and it worked for me.